# Gulp: несколько произвольных входных и выходных путей

Tags: gulp

Соответсвие входных (src) и выходных (dest) путей для таска `sass` показано ниже:

```
Alpha/Bravo/test1.sass 　→　Charlie/Delta/Echo/test1.css
Foxtrot/Golf/Hotel/test2.sass → India/Juliett/test2.css
```

Как Вы видите, в эти путях полностью отсутствует какое-либо технически важное единство концепции именования, закономерность и логическая связь. Каким образом при таком раскладе мы можем в один таск скомпилировать `test1.sass` и `test2.sass` в CSS и положить выходные файлы в папки согласно схеме выше?

Заготовка кода для ответа:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(['Alpha/Bravo/**/*.sass', 'Foxtrot/Golf/Hotel/**/*.sass'])
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(???))        
});
```

Comment: без `return` две цепочки `gulp.src(..)....`

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, прошу прощения, не совсем понял, что Вы хотели сказать. Вы бы не могли дополнить Ваше преложение до распространённого двусоставного? ^_^

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, кстати, ведь gulp-task должен обязательно что-то вернуть, иначе он просто не завершится.