# Gulp: нарушение последовательности пайпинга

Tags: gulp

### Предыстория

Смотрю, с условным сохранением файлов в `gulp` дела обстоят, мягко говоря, не очень.

- Другой мой вопрос [Gulp: несколько произвольных входных и выходных путей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739384/gulp-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) на момент задавания данного вопроса оставался без ответа. К сожалению, комментатор обидился на моё острение и так не выразился чётче, чтобы я смог понять и написать рабочее решение.
- На англоязычном сайте дела обстоят тоже не очень: например в комментарии к вопросу [Gulp: multiple source and destination paths without any unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069770/gulp-multiple-source-and-destination-paths-without-any-unity) какие-то общие слова сказаны были, но несколько часов так не увенчались даже простым рабочим решением, даже какие-то странности появились, одну из которых мы будем рассматривать в данном вопросе.
- В вопросе [gulp: set multiple gulp.src and respective gulp.dest (on gulp-sass example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998328/gulp-set-multiple-gulp-src-and-respective-gulp-dest-on-gulp-sass-example) решение я получил, но едва ли на основе его можно свободно формировать условную выходную директорию в зависимости от входной.
- `gulp-path` тоже оказался сильно ограничен: на первый взгляд он позволяет легко установить связь между входными и выходными путями, но вдруг оказалось, что он не предоставляет никакого простого решения для типового, даже рутинного `sass`-таска, где исходники хранятся в пути с последней папкой `sass`, а выходные файлы кладутся в директорию с последней папкой `css`:

  ```
  development/sass/**/*+.(sass|scss) ➡  production/css/
  ```

Нет, так не пойдёт: нужно добиться **полностью** условного вывода файлов с опеределением исходного пути и формирования выходного пути в зависимости от исходного, даже если директория исходников и выходная директория расположены расположены в разных корневых каталогах. А иначе где оно - доказательтсво на деле заверений о том, что gulp - это мощная штука?

---

### Задача

Соответствие входных и выходных путей для таска `sass` показано ниже:

```
development/source/public/sass ➡ development/build/public/css
development/source/admin/sass ➡ development/build/admin/css
```

Ничего подобного приведённый ниже код не сделает, но перед тем как продолжать попытки вывести файлы в нужный каталог, нужно разобраться с результатами отладки.

```
   gulp.task('sass', function(){

        let destinationPath = '';

        return gulp.src(`development/source/**/*.sass`)
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(rename(function (file){

                    console.log('Перед переименованием：' + destinationPath);

                    switch (file.dirname){
                        case `public\\sass`: {
                                destinationPath = `development/build/public/css`;
                                console.log('Сразу после переименования:' + destinationPath);
                                break;
                        }
                        case `admin\\sass`: {
                                destinationPath = `development/build/admin/css`;
                                console.log('Сразу после переименования:' + destinationPath);
                                break;
                        }

                        default: break;
                    }
            }))
            .pipe(plumber(console.log('После переименования:' + destinationPath)))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath));
        });
```

Итак, при запуске таска я получил следующий вывод в консоль:

```
[18:03:41] Starting 'sass'...
После переименования:
Перед переименованием:
Сразу после переименования: development/build/public/css
[18:03:41] 'sass' errored after 46 ms
[18:03:41] Error: Invalid output folder
```

То есть что прозошло: сначала gulp пропустил несколько pipe и пошёл сразу же в строку `.pipe(plumber(console.log('После переименования:' + destinationPath)))`. Естественно, что `destinationPath` - пока ещё пустая строка (а если не инициализировать `destinationPath` - таск упадёт).

Далее gulp возвращается к строке `.pipe(rename(function (file){} ...` и в нужном case-блоке осуществляет изменение значения переменной `destination`. Тем не менее, когда gulp снова доходит до `.pipe(plumber(console.log('После переименования:' + destinationPath)))` - на этот раз вроде хорошо, но тем не менее получаем ошибку `Invalid output folder`.

Вы можете объяснить происходящее? Чего я не выучил про `Node JS` и `vinyl-fs` потоки?